# Getting user information using msal user.loginRedirect()

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am working on an SPA with a /login path to a page. Here I initialize msal's useragentapplication, and pass a redirectUri (../redirect) that the b2clogin redirects to after completion.

A state and client_info (JWT) is passed with to /redirect, but I want msal to take care of that for me, so that I can call .logout() and .getUser() as well. I can see some msal.* keys in the session storage as well.

So, question: I was under the impression that I somehow could let msal take care of all this. Is there a way for me to do so?

Thanks in advance

p.s. Sorry if my question isn't clear enough, I can elaborate further, if needed.

Comment: Hi @Rasmus. MSAL does this but can you please clarify what isn't it doing for you? Is it not handling the browser redirection from Azure AD B2C?

Comment: Hi Chris, so my problem is that when I use loginRedirect, we switch from our domain/path (/#/login) to microsoft's login (ingresssandbox.onmicrosoft.com). A user then logs in, and they are redirected back to us (I've set it up to go to redirect.html). Here, on /redirect.html, how do I use MSAL again with the user's info? Hope this makes sense :)